# Grails lib directory doesn't work

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I use Grails 2.2.3. I have put jar file in lib directory, IDEA immediately resolved the dependency. But when I start app I get `NullPointerException` on class from this library. If I try it second time or more I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. I found a lot of advice how to resolve this issue but none were useful in my case.

Library (`mylib-1.jar`) compiled in maven and added to lib dir. In `BuildConfig.groovy`, dependency is mentioned as:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mylib:mylib:1'
}
```

I tried

```
grails clean
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
grails refresh-dependencies
```

but nothing helps. In result war file I can see this library in WEB-INF/lib, but even if deploy this war I get the same error.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: So you have a `.jar` file in your `/lib` directory AND `compile 'com.mylib:mylib:1'` in your `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: That's right. But I tried delete this line as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `NoClassDefFoundError` with `ClassNotFoundException`. `ClassNotFoundException` happens when a class you want isn't there, but you get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when the class is there, but a class it depends on isn't. So you're missing another jar file that this jar file depends on.

This is one of the many reasons why it's best to use dependency management instead of manually copying jar files to the lib directory. If you use a Maven repo where the jars have proper POM files, their dependencies are specified, and the resolver can download the entire tree of dependencies for you, rather than you having to find all of the jars yourself.

Comment: Thank you, now I have a direction for digging. I don't understand why it happens, because all required dependencies are connected using maven artifacts, maybe I just missed something.

Comment: @Mitya XMitya, try using JarAnalyzer to find out what you're missing http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer